# VIM S&R - using backref in the searched pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I want to search and replace something like this:

`"foo : foo"`

to

```
 "foo"
```

But of course, I need to that with a regex.

I have tried to use the below S&R command, but it seems that using backref in the searched string is not working:

```
%s/\(a-z\)\zs : \1\ze//
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`%s/\([a-z]\+\)\zs : \1\ze//`

`[a-z]` means "any character", `\+` means "repeated 1+ time".

\1 works perfectly!

Comment: Ahh! how didn't I noticed that! Thanks!